# Go Lambda with Full Access Policy 403 Access Denied on S3 PutObject

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm attempting to upload a file to an S3 bucket via Lambda in Go. I am able to read objects from the bucket with no issues, but I get `Access Denied` errors whenever I try to upload an object to the bucket.

To debug, I created the following simple Lambda function:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "context"
    "log"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3"
)

func LambdaMainWrapper() {
    data := []byte("this is some data stored as a byte slice in Go Lang!")

    // convert byte slice to io.Reader
    reader := bytes.NewReader(data)

    // upload to s3
    client := s3.New(s3.Options{Region: "us-east-2"})
    putObjectInput := &s3.PutObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(<MY_BUCKET_NAME>),
        Key:    aws.String("test-file"),
        Body:   reader,
    }
    res, err := client.PutObject(context.Background(), putObjectInput)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error uploading object to S3: ", err)
    }

    log.Println("[s3 res]", res)
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(LambdaMainWrapper)
}
```

And here is the attached policy on the execution role for the function, which to my understanding grants it all the permissions it would need to upload an object to the bucket:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ExampleStmt",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<MY_BUCKET_NAME>/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "ExampleStmt2",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<MY_BUCKET_NAME>/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "ExampleStmt3",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<MY_BUCKET_NAME>/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Lambda reports back:

```
START RequestId: XXX Version: $LATEST
2022/01/25 16:39:06 Error uploading object to S3: operation error S3: PutObject, https response error StatusCode: 403, RequestID: XXXXXXXXXX, HostID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, api error AccessDenied: Access Denied
2022/01/25 16:39:06 unexpected EOF
2022/01/25 16:39:06 unexpected EOF
END RequestId: XXX
```

I'm struggling to root cause this as an error with my Go S3 client configuration or if I've configured permissions within AWS incorrectly. It could even be that I'm sending the Body of the object incorrectly - which might explain the `unexpected EOF` messages. Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

e: using local S3 client (no lambda), I was able to succesfully upload and download objects from S3.

Comment: Ignoring the Go code for now, can you use the same credentials with the awscli to test an upload?

Comment: @jarmod thanks for asking - yes, I had done that before making this post and it worked just fine. I'll edit the main post to point that out

Comment: Does the S3 bucket have a bucket policy?

Answer (score 4):

Turns out the issue was credentials. The bucket I am accessing allows public read access, hence why my `GetObject` calls were working. However, it does not allow public write access, so `PutObject` calls were resulting in `403 Access Denied` ‍♂️ I assumed my `GetObject` calls were authenticated, but you know what they say about assuming...

The fix was simply changing

```golang
// upload to s3
client := s3.New(s3.Options{Region: "us-east-2"})
```

to

```golang
cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO())
cfg.Region = "us-east-2"
client := s3.NewFromConfig(cfg)
```

thanks @jarmod for making me realize I should attempt to use the lambda function's local default config, as one does when running on localhost !